# Terminal PS1 and colors

Tags: terminal, color

I am used from Linux to have a colored prompt in my shells and also want to implement that in my OS X Terminal.app. The Terminal reacts differently though. If I use my normal PS1 code the right side of any line will be cut down at a strange point (surely not the right end of the Terminal window). And also the next line will not show on the next line but on the same line.

expected reaction:

```
erik2:~[06:46 am]$ expectedexpectedexpectedexpectedexpectedexpectedexpect
edexpected_
```

real reaction:

```
ectedexpected_am]$ expectedexpectedexpectedexpectedexp
```

Is that normal for Terminal? Is there an alternative? Did I just code something wrong?
Have a look at my PS1 code:

```
export PS1="\033[0;34m\u:\W\e[0;32m[\@]\e[m\033[0;34m$\033[m "
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the non-printing parts of the prompt by surrounding them with `\[…\]`.

```
export PS1="\[\033[0;34m\]\u:\W\[\e[0;32m\][\@]\[\e[m\033[0;34m$\033[m\] "
```

Otherwise, readline gets confused about the remaining space on the command line.